# Running multi images/containers on the same machine or image per machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have three applications: web (www public), admin (private only auth users), next (also private for the next version aka qa/stage).

I want to use aws ecs to deploy those applications with dockers.

One way is to create a docker image for each application and create a task to run those images. meaning 4 images (or 4 containers at least) running on the same ec2. if so all the containers share the cpu and the memory capacity of the machine? which is okay to do?

Another way I thinking of is to create a cluster for each application and each ec2 in that cluster is running **ONE** application.

Which approach should I follow? or there is another approach?

Answer (score 1):

I believe spreading the containers will make your application more available. If you contain all the services in a box, the service will not run if any of the containers on the same box is down. Even if you have multiple box with all in a box setup, the bad box will keep dropping the requests. So spreading the containers/services across different boxes with a mechanism of load balancing each of them should be more reliable and available solution.